# Unit Test case for Api Controller

Tags: spring-boot, junit, controller

How to write Junit test case for this controller?

```
@PostMapping(path = "/appformsubmission")
    public AppFormChannelResponseObject saveAppForm(
            @RequestBody AppFormChannelRequestObject<AppFormDetails> requestObject) throws JsonProcessingException {

        logger.info("MwController -saveAppForm ");
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Entering MwController() method");
            logger.debug("requestObject : {}", Utility.toJsonString(requestObject));
        }
        return appFormService.submitApplicationForm(requestObject);
    }
```

It would be great if I get a sample test case as I am new to Junit. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use MockMvc in Spring Boot to do the slice testing

Answer (score 1):

From spring boot docs, by using MockMvc for MVC layer testing

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class AppFormChannelTest{

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void saveAppFormTest() throws Exception {
      AppFormChannelRequestObject body=new AppFormChannelRequestObject();
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      String json = gson.toJson(body);

      this.mockmvc.perform(post("/appformsubmission/")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(json))
    .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before diving in with `MockMVC` would suggest you to write Junit Using `TestRestTemplate`.

Refer this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testresttemplate)

This will give you a easy way to test your controllers.

Comment: I thought, TestRestTemplate  is for integration testing